# What is wrong with this font rendering on ios

Tags: ios, iphone, css, fonts

My font looks like it's rendered twice. But when I zoom in the font corrects and looks perfectly sharp.

Here is an example. 100% at the right side. zoomed in on the left side.

https://d17oy1vhnax1f7.cloudfront.net/items/2E3s1D2j29333I3s3I37/font-render.png

I looked at the css, cant find an issue. No shadows or odd css is used on the font.

The font is ProximaNovaRgRegular.
other than this, no specific css.

```
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is a question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when you are trying to use a `font-weight` that is not supported.

Regular is usually `font-weight:400;`

If these are headings:

> Apparently many mobile devices (mobile safari included) style heading tags (h1-h6) with something like font-weight: bold. If the font you are using doesn’t include a bold weight, then the browser will create a faux bold and offset that.
>
> [CSS Tricks source](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/weird-mobile-safari-font-face-problem-font-doubled-and-offset-to-the-left/#post-51866)

Comment: Totally correct! I changed the css of the page (Added the required font-family https://www.createmybooks.com/BE/nl/jouw-eigen-cursus) and looks perfectly sharp now! Thank you.